# Android NFC/HCE service returns 0x6F00 (No precise diagnosis) when selecting AID

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I have created a HCE service with an AID of F0123412349999. According to the Android HCE documentation, I need to send a SELECT APDU so the HCE service will know which service to redirect the following messages to. here is the APDU I am sending to the phone upon successful connection:

```
{ 0x00, //CLA 
  0xA4, //INS
  0x00, //P1 
  0x07, //P2
  0x07, //Lc Length Content
  0xF0, //Data (AID)
  0x12, 
  0x34, 
  0x12,
  0x34, 
  0x99, 
  0x99, 
  0x00  //Length of data expected
};
```

The transmit is successful, but what ever I do the android phone returns 0x6f00. This is translated to "No Precise Diagnosis". I have no idea what goes wrong, and apparently the error messages is somewhat vague. The following code is my HCE service:

```
public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {

    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i("HCE service", "processCommandApdu");

            byte[] answer = new byte[2];
            answer[0] = (byte) 0x90;
            answer[1] = (byte) 0x00;
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
        Log.i("HCE service", "Deactivated: " + reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("HCE service", "Created");
    }
}
```

and the AID registration:

```
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false" >

    <aid-group
        android:category="other"
        android:description="@string/app_name" >
        <aid-filter android:name="F0123412349999" />
        <aid-filter android:name="F0394148148100" />
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
```

And the manifest registration:

```
   <service
            android:name=".MyHostApduService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
        </service>
```

The reader I am using to read the Android phone is a ACR122 reader. The mobile is a HTC One. one thing that strikes me odd is the ATR that the phone sends on contact with the reader which is 0x3B80800101. I though this would be larger and contain more information, but I might be wrong.

What can I change/fix to make the android send my messages to my HCE service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for the parameters P1 and P2 in the SELECT APDU you are sending to the phone might not be valid.
Try the following:

`P1 = 0x04`

`P2 = 0x00`

You can check all the parameters for the SELECT command in a document called "Card Specification", published by Global Platform, an industry consortium.

Comment: I don't know who you are. But I will find you, and I will hug and kiss you!!! I changed the P# values and the whole thing sprang to life! Thank you, so much!

Comment: Yours was an easy question :) You'll use GlobalPlatform's Card Specification a lot if you need to write APDUs...